# Cryptography with ECC : make a multiplication of two keys with elliptic curve in javascript

Tags: javascript, elliptic-curve

so i m trying to convert two strings to points on elliptic curve then multiply the points and get another point .

Until now , i managed to convert a string to a point on the elliptic curve with this library 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/elliptic-curve

this library uses a point P on the elliptic curve and multiplied with a scalar k using elliptic curve equation to obtain another point Q on the same elliptic curve.

```
K: string (public key) 
P:a point that exists already on the elliptic curve (randomly)
Q: the result point 
kP=Q
```

i ve tried to change the `P` value and replace it with a point  that i already calculate but i can t find a way to do that !

is there any way that i can make the multiplication using the same library ? 
(JAVASCRIPT)

RECAP : 
i'm trying to make this multiplication

```
k1:public key 
P:point already exists on EC
Q1=K1.P

k2:public key 
P:point already exists on EC
Q2=K2.P

**Q3:the wanted the result 
Q3=Q2.Q1**
```

thanks :D

Comment: Multiplication of points is not something that is defined or makes sense on an elliptic curve.

Comment: By multiplication I mean that when you put two points on an elliptic curve you can make a segment which both ends are the mentioned points and you will have another point

Comment: In my case i can t make this multiplication because there is always a point that already exists on the elliptic curve

Comment: So I need to replace that point P by another one that I will generate

Comment: Check this link please to figure out what I meen! I need a function that when I give it A and B it gives me C https://www.google.tn/search?client=ms-android-huawei&tbm=isch&ei=Tg_WWvn8OsyX6ASnx7agBA&q=elliptic+curve&oq=elliptic+curve&gs_l=mobile-gws-img.3..0j0i30l4.10017.10696..10708...0....155.443.0j3..........1..mobile-gws-wiz-img.S/XSNSKpLsE%3D&tbs=itp:animated&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiwxczezMHaAhVDOJoKHZamCJYQlJcCCB0oAQ#imgrc=-PzbVBmyqcSS3M: